# changing context root of web application on websphere 6.1

Tags: java, websphere

I can change context root in the application.xml in RAD and it takes my new application context root there. Not sure what steps I need to take to change application context root permanently when application is built and deployed to anywhere other then my local server.
I did request to change context root in Websphere admin console and it did work. However when I rebult my application and redeployed to the server it went back to the original context root.
What do I need to change at the application build/deploy time for it to take my new application context root? Is it the name of my application war file ?

Thank you in advance for any information on this subject

Answer (score 0):

The context root is set in the EAR file. Look for META-INF/application.xml. You have the context root for your applications there.